# How to make private GitHub repo available to other organization team members?

Tags: git, github

New to GitHub, and I used Xcode to create a repo, add all the files, and push it to our organization's (paid) GitHub account.

The repo is "private", and I can see it listed as one of MY repositories.  HOWEVER -- there doesn't seem to be a way to add the repo to the other members of the TEAM.  The repo doesn't show as existing to the add repo to team command.  The members of the team ARE all members of the organization.

I made the repo "private" because the option of "public" said it would be available to ANYONE. Didn't want to do that.

*So -- do I need to do "Transfer Ownership" on this repo to move it to our organization?*

If so, how should I have created the repo at the organization level to begin with?

Comment: Try to add colaborators, by going to your repo -> `Settings` -> `Collaborators`, and then add their GH names to the field. An invite will be sent and they can start contributing

Comment: Here are the steps : https://help.github.com/en/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository

Comment: @mnestorov -- Aren't "Collaborators" specifically people from OUTSIDE the organization?  I'm just focused on granting access to the members of the team that ARE members of the organization...

Comment: @SMGreenfield I don't think that collaborators are only limited to outside people. If you follow [this link](https://help.github.com/en/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository) and [this one](https://help.github.com/en/articles/access-permissions-on-github#enterprise-accounts), you can see how to add people to your project who have rights to the project as well. I do not know if organization members ALREADY have read-write rights to all repos in an organization, but I would assume they do by defualt....

Comment: @mnestorov -- problem solved by transferring depot to Organization, and just added the repo to one of our "teams", which organization members are part of.  The reason I believe collaborators only refer to people "outside" the organization, is that for a paid account on a PRIVATE repo, there are a limited number of collaborator licenses you can issue, and that number is DIFFERENT than organization member licenses.

Comment: @SMGreenfield I am glad you solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming across this in the future -- YES -- a "private" repo should be transferred to the organization if you expect to share it with members of your organization's team.

Comment: this is NOT an answer. AT LEAST explain how you would transfer ownership!

Answer (score 3):

To move your private repo so that teams in your organization can access, do the following:

1. Assume you have an organization set up such as 'FoobarCompany' with a team that includes the person owning the private repo
2. From github.com//<repo_name>/settings#danger-zone click on 'Transfer'
3. You will be prompted to enter the company name, and then (after security authorization step of typing in the repro name) be prompted for the teams that will have access from the company
4. You will see the repro disappear from your user, but if you look at the company (github.com/FoobarCompany) you should see the repro

Pretty simple, but do check that you have the company name correct and you are not assigning the repro to the right organization

If you want to invite people outside of your organization, from your repository, go:

Settings/Manage Access and Invite a collaborator